# Generate static html from the content of the site with Joomla 3.x api

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

anybody knows how to access to the content of a Joomla site through the API?

I'm trying to create a component which download the content of my Joomla site in html.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Any Joomla website, by default, will have it's content available in RSS format by just adding `format=feed` to the end of the URL (mainly on category blog pages). It is relatively easy to parse RSS fees if you want the Joomla site's content available on other websites.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is an api for what you need. Aside from the rss mentioned above, you might want to use a site crawler..

Answer (score -1):

I do not think you need to create a component like that, should use obGrabber component because it has ability of pull content from RSS feeds, or even from HTML pages.